# Running maven plugins defined in a local project

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way for a maven project to contain local maven plugin (maven mojo classes) that can be used within the project directly, from the local classpath, without a need to do a maven install first?

Comment: No it is not and does not really make sense. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I'm not saying it's impossible. But I doubt any other way will make things easier. So what's the problem with doing the maven install? Better solve that.

Comment: I'm coming from other build systems (gradle and grunt.js) and would like to replicate this simple behavior: you put some build related code as part of your project (which is say, a webapp) and then execute it easily on demand via build tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Maven the "build related code" (though declarative, not imperative) lies in your project's [POM (Project Object Model, pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)). The runtime environment for these declarations is the installed Maven.

Once you become familiar with POMs and its ideas and concepts it's even simpler than coding build related things – at least from my, and many many others, POV.

If you really want or even must code something use [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki) to use Groovy code inside your POM or [create your own plugin(s)](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html) and use Maven as runtime environment for them.

Comment: Great, so if I add my groovy code inside my POM how can I invoke it on demand (not part of the automatic life cycle) -- like in ant or gradle: mvn myTask myParameters

Comment: @Ivan You can put your GMavenPlus declaration in a [Build Profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and activate it in one of the various ways described there on demand.